# Calculate using residues $\oint\limits_\gamma\frac{\tan z}{z + 2}dz$, where $\gamma: |z + 2| = 2$ - a closed loop, run counterclockwise.

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-integration, residue-calculus

> Calculate using residues $\oint\limits_\gamma\frac{\tan z}{z + 2}dz$, where $\gamma: |z + 2| = 2$ - a closed loop, run counterclockwise

Hi. Here is what I have tried:

Assuming Isolated singularity is single: $z = -2$ (equating the denominator of the integrand to $0$)

Using formula:
$$
\oint_{\gamma} f(z) d z=2 \pi i \sum_{k=1}^{n} \operatorname{Res}\left(f(z) ; z=z_{k}\right)
$$
we have:

$$
\oint_{|z + 2| = 2} \frac{\tan z}{z + 2} d z=2 \pi i \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{\tan z}{z + 2}; z=-2\right)=(*)
$$

$$
\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{\tan z}{z + 2}; z=-2\right)= \lim _{z \rightarrow -2} \left[\frac{\tan z}{z + 2}\left(z-(-2)\right)\right] = -\tan 2 \approx 2,185$$

$$
(*)= 2 \pi i \cdot (\tan 2) \approx 6,2831852i\cdot(2,185) \approx 13,7288i  
$$

Sounds good, but I am not sure whether $z = -2$ is the only point? My teacher told me that there also $\tan z = 0$ might give some points, but she is also not sure...

If somebody knows, explain, please.

Comment: $tgz = \tan z?$

Comment: @AndréArmatowski yes, will change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that $\tan0=0$ creates no problem. However, the fact that $\tan$ is undefined at $-\frac\pi2$ does. The answer is$$2\pi i\left(\operatorname{res}_{z=-2}\frac{\tan z}{z+2}+\operatorname{res}_{z=-\pi/2}\frac{\tan z}{z+2}\right)=2\pi i\left(\tan(-2)+\frac2{\pi-4}\right).$$

Comment: @AndréArmatowski Sure. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you, but where is a residue in z=-2 point then?

Comment: It was a typo. I meant $z=-2$.